# Disable Weblogic 12c own authentication

Tags: spring, weblogic

I've got a Spring Boot application running fine locally in tomcat using Spring security which authenticates users from a database. When I deploy this to Weblogic it seems like weblogic is adding it's own authentication on top. Is there a way of disabling this per managed server? So a call to the URL will use the Spring security and not the Weblogic one?

I understand you can use the built in authentication from Weblogic but as we may move to tomcat in the near future I'd rather use Spring authentication in the mean time. Plus Weblogic is an absolute pain to use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable Weblogic authentication for your domain by adding below properties in your weblogic config.xml:

```
<enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>false</enforce-valid-basic-auth
  -credentials>
```

For disable weblogic authenication follow this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E80738_01/pt854pbh2/eng/pt/tfee/task_ConfiguringOracleWebLogicServertoDisableAuthentication-ad7e32.html#topofpage):

Comment: Sorry my understanding of weblogic isn't great but does a domain = a weblogic server? So I could disable it on one of the weblogic managed servers but not on others?

Comment: No. A `Domain` can contain one or more `Managed Servers`. Each `Domain` will have one `config.xml` file and using this solution you can disable it for all of the `Managed Servers` in that `Domain`. That said, I don't think this solution is what you are looking for.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it now just to confirm. Ideally I just want to disable it for a single managed server in a domain which doesn't seem unreasonable. I'll raise a request into Oracle if no one has any suggestions in a few hours.

Comment: Nope, still getting the same popup credentials box with that setting changed and weblogic restarted.

Comment: I think if you make DefaultAuthenticator=OPTIONAL (in the Console), and do not use Security Provider | virtualization=true, WL will only be picking up the first Authenticator in the list of providers.

Comment: I had Weblogic re-installed and added the original suggested line in. It all appears to be working now thankfully.

Comment: I have read that It happens with basic authentication but. Does someone know if with other authentication protocol too?